# Как включить порождение кода при разработке GUI на Swing, в NetBeans?

Tags: java, swing, gui, netbeans

Автоматическое создание обработчика события не работает.
Никаких глубоких конфигов не трогала, в чём может быть проблема? Куда копать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
NetBeans IDE 8.2, JDK 8

Comment: почему swing а не javaFX ?

Comment: потому что по заданию требуется именно swing

Comment: советую переключиться на javaFX и использовать Scene Builder. Когда в нем накидаете графику - там есть вывод кода, в одном из пунктов меню. @menu > view > show sample skeleton code@

Comment: конкретезируйте, что именно у вас не получается? создать обработчик события кнопки?

Comment: ну например, при двойном нажатии на button не создается обработчик, и в источнике ничего не изменяется, в коде кнопки все серое, как на скрине выше. При удалении пункта кнопки actionPerformed, тоже ничего не происходит в коде программы

Comment: не полагайтесь на "Автоматическое создание". задайте кнопке Id (имя) и в коде пропишите слушатель для событий мыши. На пример что то вроде - jButton = btn1; btn1.addEventHandler(Mouse.CLICKED, this::mouseClickListener); mouseClickListener(MouseEvent e) { ... }